# Postman response schema in API Documentation

Tags: postman, openapi

I created a collection in Postman that should work as my API documentation. I know, that for every endpoint I can save example responses, that will be included in the documentation.

Now I would like to include a response schema as well, so that people see a general definition of the data types and structure of the response. In OpenApi this is possible within the "response" block like this:

```
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "200 response",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/User"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

...
 
"components": {
  "schemas": {
    "User": {
      "title": "User Schema",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Postman as well? I searched the documentation for quite some time but could not find anything useful except for one line [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/publishing-your-api/documenting-your-api/) that sounds like it should be possible:

> Each collection / request listing indicates the method, required authorization type, URL, description, headers, request and **response structures**, and examples.

Comment: This isn't possible for OpenAPI schemas. That extract from docs relates to what is automatically generated in the Collection Documentation. You could add that within the description but not in the same way as you would see the request/response examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description supports markdown language you can use below content :**

````
# Schema:

```
  "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "200 response",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/User"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

...
 
"components": {
  "schemas": {
    "User": {
      "title": "User Schema",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```
````

**output:**

[image]

Comment: It's sad, that this is not possible. We wanted to use postman as a tool to maintain and publish our OpenAPI specification in an "easy to use" way. We will now stick to plain old yaml files, that we edit in SwaggerHub and distribute via a deploy pipeline.

Comment: @MrShorly why can't you provide that yaml file as a link in the postman documentation ?

Comment: just upload the file to an open git repository and do `<a href="https://github.com/username/fileshare/blob/main/schema.yaml?raw=true">Download YAML </a>`

Comment: just paste this in your postman documentaiton

Comment: I could do that, but then I would have to maintain two documentations at the same time: the OpenAPI yaml as well as the Postman collection. The postman collection can be generated from OpenAPI, but the OpenAPI schema can not be extracted from postman (at least not with all details). So the OpenAPI schema is superior. I hoped that the two had a similar feature set, because then we would have used postman.

Comment: Where are you storing open api schema file ?

Comment: The tag I showed creates a downloadable link to the yaml file ,

Comment: Currently in Bitbucket, but we will move to GitHub soon.

Comment: it need not be in github , the file can be anywhere in public domain , just point src="https//wwww.publicwebsite/youryaml.yaml"